# C++ - Linked list strings are repeating

Tags: c++

**UPDATE: This is C++, not C**

I am creating a students linked list in C. The problem is when I run it:

```
Input:
ID: 1
Name: John
Mark: 10

ID: 2
Name: Jane
Mark: 6

ID: 0 /*to end the list*/

Output:
1   Jane   10
2   Jane   6
```

You can see ID 1 is repeating the name from ID 2, if I have more ID like 5 ID, it will repeat the name from ID 5

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
    int ID;
    char *Name;
    float Mark;
};

struct ttNode {
    struct student data;
    struct ttNode *pNext;
};
typedef ttNode NODE;
struct ttList {
    NODE *pHead, *pTail;
};
typedef ttList LIST;
void CreateEmptyList (LIST &list) {
    list.pHead = list.pTail = NULL;
}
int IsEmptyList(LIST list) {
    if((list.pHead==NULL) && (list.pTail==NULL)) return 1;
    return 0;
}
void AddHead (LIST &list, NODE *pNew) {
    if(IsEmptyList(list))
    {
        list.pHead = list.pTail = pNew;
    }
    else
    {
        pNew -> pNext = list.pHead;
        list.pHead = pNew;
    }
}
void AddTail (LIST &list, NODE *pNew) {
    if (IsEmptyList(list)) {
        list.pHead = list.pTail = pNew;
    }
    else
    {
        list.pTail -> pNext = pNew;
        list.pTail = pNew;
    }
}
NODE *CreateNode (int id, char *name, float mark) {
    NODE *p;
    p = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        printf("Allocation error!");
        exit(0);
    }
    p->data.ID = id;
    p->data.Name = name;
    p->data.Mark = mark;
    p->pNext=NULL;
    return p;
}
void Input_AddHead (LIST &list) {
    int id;
    char *name;
    float mark;
    NODE *pNew;
    CreateEmptyList(list);
    do {
        fflush(NULL);
        printf("Input ID (0 to end): ");
        scanf("%d", &id);
        if(id == 0)
            break;
        printf("Input name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);
        printf("Input mark: ");
        scanf("%f", &mark);
        printf("\n");

        pNew=CreateNode(id,name,mark);
        AddHead(list,pNew);
    } while (1);
}
void Output(LIST list)
{
    NODE *p = list.pHead;
    while(p)
    {
        printf("\t%d \t%s \t%f\n ", p->data.ID, p->data.Name, p->data.Mark);
        p = p -> pNext;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    LIST list;
    Input_AddHead(list);
    Output(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Xcode keep warn the `scanf("%s", name);` name is uninitallize in here
If I follow Xcode by changing `char *name;` to `char *name = nullptr;`, the program crash at Inputing name. So what's wrong in this code.

Comment: this isn't C, this is C++. C doesn't have references

Comment: the question should be moved to correct tag vitz, c++

Comment: Ok, sorry, edited

Comment: this question should be moved to the pool of closed questions, this is basically a non-MCVE question with a lot of bugs in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `name` pointer in list is being assigned as pointer.

```
p->data.Name = name;
```

Hence `p->data.Name` will always points to updated value in `name`.

Try instead as below.

```
p->data.Name = strdup(name);
```

> Where strdup calculates the space needed and allocates the memory
>   dynamically and copies the input string and returns the newly
>   allocated pointer. Also note that `strdup` is not standard `C` or `C++`, so it isn't portable.

If you don't want to use `strdup` allocate the memory to `p->data.Name` dynamically and use `strcpy` to copy.

---

Adding on to answer the main problem with your code.

```
void Input_AddHead (LIST &list) {
    .....
    char *name;
    .....
    do {
        .....
        printf("Input name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);

        ......              

        pNew=CreateNode(id,name,mark);
        .....
     } while (1);
}
```

As you see your `name` is not been allocated and referencing it will lead to undefined behavior.

```
    scanf("%s", name);
```

Hence I suggest you to change as below.

```
void Input_AddHead (LIST &list) {
    .....
    char *name;
    .....
    do {
        .....
        char line[100];
        printf("Input name: ");
        scanf("%s",line);

        ......              
         name = strdup(line);
        pNew=CreateNode(id,name,mark);
        .....
     } while (1);
}
```

int that case pointer assignment like below in `CreateNode` should work as it is.
Without any additional allocation to `p->data.Name`.

```
p->data.Name = name;
```

Comment: @superquanganh Glad I was able to help you.

Comment: It is worth mentioning, that *strdup* is not part of C language's standard library, so it is not available in every OS. It is in BSD and POSIX though, so it is fine as long as you only require OSX, Linux etc compatibility.

Comment: You forget that `name` is an uninitialized pointer with no memory assigned to it to read the name with `scanf`. That should crash the program already.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Right you are. I was diverted to duplicate values in the list as OP mentioned that is the issue. Anyway I addressed the actual issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the `createNode` function, the statement   `p->data.Name = name;` does not copy the `name`. To copy the `name`, you will have to use `strcpy` library function.

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

Before that, you will also have to allocate memory for `name` using `malloc`. And the memory allocated should be the `sizeof` the `name` you have passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

first look the problem seems to be

```
p->data.Name = name;
```

this should do as a quick fix

```
p->data.Name = strdup(name);
```

but then its always better of using `malloc` and `strcpy`

there are quite a few other `errors` I can still see but I'll leave that to you

you seem to be mixing the `c++ references` with `c-pointers` and I'm not sure if your code is even compiling, if it is **which is highly doubt** it's probably still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behaviour, `name` is uninitialized when you call `scanf` function :

```
 void Input_AddHead ( // current codee
      ...
      printf("Input name: ");
      scanf("%s", name);   // <--- name is uninitialized
      printf("Input mark: ");
```

you should create temporary buffer, enter a string into this buffer then make a copy of string and pass it to function which creates new node:

```
void Input_AddHead ( // ... fix
    int id;
    float mark;
    NODE *pNew;
    CreateEmptyList(list);
    do {
        fflush(NULL);
        printf("Input ID (0 to end): ");
        scanf("%d", &id);
        if(id == 0)
            break;
        printf("Input name: ");
        char buf[80];     // create temp buffer
        scanf("%s", buf); // enter data
        char* name = (char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1); // make copy
        strcpy(name,buf);                          // of string 
        printf("Input mark: ");
        scanf("%f", &mark);
        printf("\n");

        pNew=CreateNode(id,name,mark); // you can pass pointer to unique string
```

Comment: may I ask why I got downvote ?

Comment: probably because `void Input_AddHead (LIST &list)` isn't C, it's C++

Comment: lol, but it is the solution to OP problem, not call strdup , really funny.

Comment: really I don't know why, OP also uses refs for "C" code. not using strdup doesn't solve any issue BTW

Comment: you're right about the "uninitialized pointer" bit. Stay away from those "wall of code" questions. They often contain many bugs.